# Why does Android Studio create classes with "public" modifier as default?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Isn't it a bad practice to create classes with "public" modifier?

If we don't want that another applications should reach our classes why should we use "public" modifier? Can we change the default modifier for classes?

I know that we could adjust the class members how we want, but isn't it better to create all classes without a modifier(package-private)?

Comment: Have you tested doing that?

Your classes have to be accessible by Android itself too.

Comment: @Pemapmodder i was going to change all my classes to package-private. But i was not sure that i am doing the right or not. That's why i posted the quesiton.

Comment: Access Modifiers is the way of specifying the accessibility of a class and its members with respective to other classes and members.

Comment: @eren130 you can try first testing if that works, then edit this question to ask why this method works/not work.

Comment: @Pemapmodder thanks for advices. Can you tell me please; in which kind of situations android tries to access my classes? Which kind of classes could be package-private, or which kind of classes should be public? For example; my FTP settings class(which contains password, username...) has package-private. What about another examples?

Comment: Actually, I am not quite sure, but this line inspired me: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick It states that the method must be **public**, so this may mean that Android virtually triggers your methods with limitation to visibility. I similarly apply the same theory to classes that interact with the Android API from XML documents, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it a bad practice to create classes with "public" modifier?

Depends on the expected use of the class but, in general, I'd say no.

> If we don't want that another applications should reach our classes
> why should we use "public" modifier?

Well, if you want it protected from use then protect it.

> Can we change the default modifier for classes?

Yes, it's a template which you can edit.** Here's how...

Press `Ctrl+Alt+S` to bring up the *Settings* dialog, expand the *Editor* tab and select *File and Code Templates*. On the right you'll see some tabs. Select *Files* (may be *Templates* depending on your version) and the one you're looking for is `Class`. Edit the file as you see fit.

** *Assuming Android Studio has the same settings options as its mother Intellij.*

Comment: This does nothing.

Comment: @Waldmann, there was a typo in the shortcut (fixed) but it does exactly what I said if you simply open the settings.

Comment: people do not use templates when writing classes

Comment: @Waldmann, that is a ridiculous claim and absolutely false.